# How to use Route53 Domain commandlets in AWS Lambda?

Tags: powershell, aws-lambda

I get an error when running route 53 domain commandlets in lambda, they run fine locally and I can successfully run other commandlets in lambda, for example, s3.

I already gave the IAM user full administrative permissions, tested locally and with other commandlets, and even tried running the command with an alias, and googled the error I get.

This is the basic script:

```bsh
#Requires -Modules @{ModuleName='AWSPowerShell.NetCore';ModuleVersion='3.3.563.1'}
# Uncomment to send the input event to CloudWatch Logs
Write-Host (ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $LambdaInput -Compress -Depth 5)
$r53domains = Get-R53DDomainList -AccessKey "xxxx" -SecretKey "xxx"
foreach ($domain in $r53domains){write-host "Domainlist = $($domain.DomainName)"}
```

I would expect output like:
Domainlist = xxxx.com
Domainlist = xxxxxx.nl

However, in Lambda I get the following error:

```
[Error] - No such device or address
No such device or address: InvalidOperationException
   at Amazon.Lambda.PowerShellHost.PowerShellFunctionHost.ExecuteFunction(Stream inputStream, ILambdaContext context)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Stream , Stream , LambdaContextInternal )

   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1 creationTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at Amazon.Runtime.HttpWebRequestMessage.GetResponseAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpHandler`1.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Unmarshaller.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointDiscoveryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointDiscoveryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.PowerShell.Cmdlets.R53D.GetR53DDomainListCmdlet.CallAWSServiceOperation(IAmazonRoute53Domains client, ListDomainsRequest request)
   at Amazon.PowerShell.Cmdlets.R53D.GetR53DDomainListCmdlet.Execute(ExecutorContext context)
No such device or address: SocketException
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer.

My Lambda is running in region eu-west-1 (Ireland) but route 53 should be regionless, as can also be found here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/aws-regions-and-windows-powershell/

However, when I ran the commands locally using the -Verbose switch it showed that the command was run in region us-east-1. After adding the -Region us-east-1 to the powershell command in Lambda it ran fine.